# Sending post request with both data and JSON parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to send a post request with both data and JSON fields, such as:

```
my_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
pickled = pickle.dumps(my_df)
pickled_b64 = base64.b64encode(pickled)

my_name = "my_csv_name.csv"

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5003/rcvdf', data = pickled_b64, json= {"name": my_name})
```

Notice that pickled_b64 is of type 'bytes'.

But on the other end, I get only the data and no JSON at all:

```
@api.route('/rcvdf', methods=['POST'])
def test_1():
    data_pickeled_b64_string = request.data
    json_data = request.json #This is None
```

Is it even possible to pass two variables in such a way?

--edit

**Solution**

thanks to the comments I tried different approach - and passed the variable by headers:

Sending Side:

```
my_name = "my_csv.csv"

r = requests.post('http://localhost:5003/rcvdf', data=pickled_b64, headers={"name": my_name})
```

Receiving Side:

```
@app.route('/rcvdf', methods=['POST'])
def rcvdf():
    data_pickeled_b64_string = request.data
    name = request.headers['name']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requests.post(url, json=payload)` is just a shortcut for `requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))`

> Note, the json parameter is ignored if either data or files is passed.

[docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

So, no, it is not possible to pass both `data` and `json` parameters.

Comment: Is it possible to pass both `data` and `files` parameters?

Comment: @xilopaint yes, passing both `data` and `files` works, but the content type in this case is `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1):

**An Alternative method:**

**Since base64 encoding has ASCI format you can convert it to simple string object.**

Then you can do it by embedding your pickled_b64 in your json data:

```
import base64, request


pickled_b64 = str(base64.b64encode("hello world".encode()), encoding="utf-8")
json_data = {"Pickled_B64": pickled_b64, "Name": "my_csv_name.csv"}
send_request = requests.post('http://localhost:5003/rcvdf', json=json_data)
print(send_request.json())
```

and on your backend side:

```
from flask import make_response, jsonify

@api.route('/rcvdf', methods=['POST'])
def test_1():
    pickled_b64 = request.json.get('Pickled_B64', None)
    name = request.json.get('Name', None)
    reserve_dict = {"Status": "Got it", "name": name, "pickled_b64": pickled_b64}
    reserve_response = make_response(jsonify(reserve_dict), 200)
    return reserve_response
```

Comment: Hey, I keep getting:
 'json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).'
But I already decided to pass the name by headers. Anyway, Thank You very much for your help!!!

Comment: @DanielFridman update your question and put your new codes i will check it

Comment: @DanielFridman did you use my flask side version too ?

Comment: yea, But there's a problem with the json and all the encoding

Comment: @DanielFridman may you post your error message?

Comment: @DanielFridman did you replace your dataframe object with my "hello world" string ? if yes then update your question and put your code; maybe you did it wrong ...